# Merging in R based on conditions

Tags: r

For two example dataframes:

```
df1 <- structure(list(name = c("Katie", "Eve", "James", "Alexander", 
"Mary", "Barrie", "Harry", "Sam"), postcode = c("CB12FR", "CB12FR", 
"NE34TR", "DH34RL", "PE46YH", "IL57DS", "IP43WR", "IL45TR")), .Names = c("name", 
"postcode"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), postcode = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("name", "postcode")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))

df2 <-structure(list(name = c("Katie", "James", "Alexander", "Lucie", 
"Mary", "Barrie", "Claire", "Harry", "Clare", "Hannah", "Rob", 
"Eve", "Sarah"), postcode = c("CB12FR", "NE34TR", "DH34RL", "DL56TH", 
"PE46YH", "IL57DS", "RE35TP", "IP43WQ", "BH35OP", "CB12FR", "DL56TH", 
"CB12FR", "IL45TR"), rating = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L)), .Names = c("name", "postcode", "rating"
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), postcode = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), rating = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("name", "postcode", "rating")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

I wish to merge the two dataframes, so the ratings on df2 are added to df1. I would normally use:

ratings.df <- merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "postcode", all.x = TRUE)

HOWEVER.... 
I wish to merge only if:
1. The postcodes in df2 are unique (i.e. if there are multiple postcodes for each name (or different names), these won't be merged).
2. AND the first three letters of the name are the same in both dataframes.

(I am happy for blanks for the postcodes that don't have a rating (I can then do these manually)).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `sqldf` package? You can merge data.frames in R using this package. Do this by using `JOIN` statements.

In terms of the conditional merging, this can be accomplished by using `CASE` statements in SQL.

So, for your first condition, you can use a `CASE`  where the `COUNT(postcode) = ‘1’` and you `GROUP BY name`, so that for each name that has 1 postcode assigned to it, you can `JOIN`.

Another option is to `gather` using `tidyr`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `dplyr` solution, we could first eliminate duplicates within `df2$postcode`, then join the dataframe to `df1`:

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- df2 %>%
  distinct(postcode, .keep_all = TRUE)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df3, by = c("postcode")) %>%
  filter(substr(name.x, 1, 3) == substr(name.y, 1, 3)) %>%
  rename(name = name.x) %>%
  mutate(name.y = NULL)
```

---

This would yield

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  name      postcode rating
  <chr>     <chr>     <int>
1 Katie     CB12FR        1
2 James     NE34TR        1
3 Alexander DH34RL        1
4 Mary      PE46YH        3
5 Barrie    IL57DS        1
```

Is this what you were trying to achieve?